# Check If Digits in Input Different

Tags: python, algebra

I need to check if all digits in number are different.

I.e: 123 - would be spotted as "different", but 121 wouldn't as the first item is equal to the last item.

Here's what I come up with :

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 

a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n] 

print("\nList is - ", a)

result = False;

if len(a) > 0 :
    result = all(elem == a[0] for elem in a)

if result :
     print("All Elements in List are Equal")
else:      
    print("All Elements in List are Not Equal")
```

But, unfortunately, such input as "1,2,1" is treated as "All Elements in List are Not Equal".

Comment: Convert to a set and compare the length.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Not most efficient but you can convert to set and check if lenghts are equal. Sets store unique elements so it will work as expected.

```
def is_unique_number(number):
    num_str=str(number)
    if len(num_str) == set(num_str):
        return True
    return False
```